# Getting Value error when reading file into a dictionary using python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm trying to read a file into a dictionary so that the key is the word and the value is the number of occurrences of the word. I have something that should work, but when I run it, it gives me a

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

This is what I have right now:

```
try:
    f = open('fileText.txt', 'r+')
except:
    f = open('fileText.txt', 'a')
    def read_dictionary(fileName):
         dict_word = {}  #### creates empty dictionary
         file = f.read()
         file = file.replace('\n', ' ').rstrip()
         words = file.split(' ')
         f.close()
         for x in words:
             if x not in result:
                 dict_word[x] = 1
             else:
                 dict_word[x] += 1
         print(dict_word)
print read_dictionary(f)
```

Comment: Your variable called `fileName` is actually the file handle. Your variable called `file` is the text contents of the file. At the very least, it would make it easier to reason about where the problem is if your names described the things assigned to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because file was opened in `write mode`. Write mode is `not readable`.

Try this:

```
 with open('fileText.txt', 'r') as f:
     file = f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a context manager to avoid manually keeping track of which files are open.  Additionally, you had some mistakes involving using the wrong variable name.  I've used a `defaultdict` below to simplify the code, but it isn't really necessary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def read_dict(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        d = defaultdict(int)
        words = f.read().split() #splits on both spaces and newlines by default
        for word in words:
            d[word] += 1
        return d
```